# Does Drupal Answers use Drupal?

Tags: support, faq

Is *Drupal Answers* a Drupal site, or is it created using other software?

Answer (score 7):

*Drupal Answers*, as any other Stack Exchange site, is not built on Drupal, but using C#. It uses [Microsoft ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) version 4.0 and [ASP.NET MVC 3](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3) as frameworks, and [Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx) as view engine; the other used libraries include:

- [Cruise Control .NET](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET)
- [DotNetOpenId](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/)
- [MarkdownSharp](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/)
- [PageDown](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/) (the editor used for the posts)
- [Prettify](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/)

#### Reference

- [Which tools and technologies build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10369/140449)