# User name "unknown" for "community wiki" post

Tags: discussion, bug

I've done a minor change to the [community wiki post](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/895/25879). It's showing the modified user name as "unknown" (as follows)

[image]

But the [Top Questions](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/) page, and [revision history](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/895/revisions) shows the modified user name correctly.

[image]

Is that a bug? or Did I miss something to understand?